# Magento - updated category, missing thousands of products

Tags: magento-1.8, category, upgrade, bug

Recently updated a category in our Magento install (adjusting title and meta data)

We have 1 main category, with 8 sub categories. Each of these sub categories *had* around 1000 - 3000 products in each.

After said update of category, our top 5 categories are now showing only 1000 products, the products are still in the database, just not assigned to a category.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is it a server timeout issue when re-indexing?

We're running 1.8.0.0.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: Pointing this to the duplicate; LCT please let me know if you are having a different issue (I've seen Suhosin cause this same problem as well)

Comment: php version upgrade trap, max_input_vars does a trim as the default is set at 1000.

Answer (score 0):

This is todo with with the php_value max_input_vars value which is 1000 by default. The simplest way is to increase this value in the htaccess or php.ini file but the question is answered in full here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851064/why-does-magento-keep-only-the-first-1000-products-in-a-category-after-saving-t